# How is variable substitution taken into account in natural deduction?

Tags: proof-verification, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

My question concerns variable substitution in natural deduction.  As an example, if one wants to prove:

$T_R, ((a + c = b + c) \to a = b) \vdash (a = b \to (a + c = b + c))$

where $T_R$ is the axioms of the real numbers, then I suppose one would write the proof something like this:

1. $(a + c = b + c) \to a = b \vdash (a + c = b + c) \to a = b$  --- [Axiom rule]
2. $x = a + c \vdash x = a + c$ --- [Axiom rule]
3. $y = b + c \vdash y = b + c$ --- [Axiom rule]
4. $T_R, x = a + c \vdash a = x + (-c)$ --- [Derivable from field axioms]
5. $T_R, y = b + c \vdash b = y + (-c)$ --- [Derivable from field axioms]
6. $a = b \vdash a = b$ --- [Axiom rule]
7. $T_R, x = a + c, y = b + c, a = b \vdash x + (-c) = b$ --- [=E: 4, 6]
8. $T_R, x = a + c, y = b + c, a = b \vdash x + (-c) = y + (-c)$ --- [=E: 5, 7]
9. $T_R, x = a + c, y = b + c, ((a + c = b + c) \to a = b), a = b \vdash x = y$ --- [Modus ponens from 1 and 8]
10. $T_R, x = a + c, y = b + c, ((a + c = b + c) \to a = b), a = b \vdash a + c = y$ --- [=E: 4, 9]
11. $T_R, x = a + c, y = b + c, ((a + c = b + c) \to a = b), a = b \vdash a + c = b + c$ --- [=E: 5, 10]
12. $T_R, x = a + c, y = b + c, ((a + c = b + c) \to a = b) \vdash a = b \to (a + c = b + c)$ --- [${\to}I$: 11]

The problem obviously is how to discharge the $x = a + c$ and $y = b + c$ conditions.  Some have told me that such statements do not need to be introduced as assumptions, you just wave your hand somehow and it works.  This doesn't seem satisfactory to me.  How can you get to lines 7 and 8 without introducing the assumptions in 2 and 3?  And if this is correct, then how do I discharge them?  If not correct, what is the actual mechanism that allows us to go to lines 7 and 8.  Surely there must be some law or rule of inference that validates this move.

Comment: I cannot understand 9... From 2. $x=a+c$ and 3. $y=b+c$ with $a+b$ and $=$E you can derive $x=b+c$ and then $x=y$ again by $=$E.

Comment: And the same for 11. from $a+c=a+c$ and $a=b$ by $=$E you can get $a+c=b+c$.

Comment: Hmm, I think I used a bad example, I should have just used the one I was working on, which was proving that $a + c > b + c \to a > b \vdash a > b \to a + c > b + c$.  I realize now that the proof for my example is rather trivial, as per your answer below.  I'm not sure how to solve this one, though.  Should I just create a new question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you can simplify it:

1) $a=b$ --- assumption [a]

2) $\vdash a+c=a+c$ --- $=$I (no assumptions)

3) $a+c=b+c$ --- from 1) and 2) by $=$E, where $a+c=x+c$ is $\phi$, 2) is $\phi[a/x]$ and 3) is $\phi[b/x]$

> 4) $\vdash a=b \to (a+c=b+c)$ --- from 1) and 3) by $\to$-intro, discharging [a].

As you can see, we need only the rules for $=$ and no non-logical axioms.

---

There is nothing peculiar regardind *substitution* in Natural Deduction.

We have only to avoid being misleaded by the symbolism; usually, when we write $\phi[t/x]$ we are meaning that **all** the free occurrences of $x$ in $\phi$ are replaced with $t$.

This symbolism may "force" us to an unnecessary restriction in the [substitution rule for formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Equality_and_its_axioms) that, in axiomatic form, is:

> $x = y → (\phi → \phi')$, where $\phi'$ is obtained by replacing any number [i.e. zero or more, but not necessarily all] of free occurrences of $x$ in $\phi$ with $y$.

Comment: Is it possible to prove the reverse, that is: $a + c = b + c \to a = b$ without non-logical axioms?  The only way I can think of doing this is adding $-c$ to both sides of $a + c = b + c$, but this requires the field axioms

Comment: Now that I think about, I'm pretty sure that this **cannot** be proved without the field axioms, in the same way that you cannot in general say that $f(a) = f(b) \to a = b$, as I can think of many functions for which this would not be true.

Comment: @esotechnica - correct; to prove $a+c=b+c \to a=b$ in first-order arithmetic, we need induction (i.e. a non-logical axiom).

Comment: Thanks Mauro, I should have given the example that I was actually working on, which was using inequality symbols rather than equality.  I will post a new question as I am stuck with this.